# Understanding the extension ElementAt(index)

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

Consider this code:

```
int size = 100 * 1000 * 1000;
var emu = Enumerable.Range(0, size);
var arr = Enumerable.Range(0, size).ToArray();
```

when I call emu.ElementAt(size-10) and arr.ElementAt(size-10) and measure the time the arr is much faster (the array is 0.0002s compared to IEnumerable 0.59s).

As I understand it, the extention method ElementAt() have the signature

```
public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index)
```

and since the 'source' is a IEnumerable the logic carried out would be similar - opposed to what I see where the array is accessed directly.

Could someone please explain this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an optimization performed at *execution-time*. Although the call isn't overloaded, it is able to check (using `is` or `as`) whether the source is actually an `IList<T>`. If it is, it's able to go directly to the right element.

Various other calls do this - notable `Count()` which is optimised for `ICollection<T>` and (as of .NET 4) the nongeneric `ICollection` interface.

One of the downsides of extension methods is that all these optimizations have to be performed by the implementation itself - types can't override anything to "opt in" to optimizing extension methods. That means the optimizations have to all be known by the original implementor :(

Comment: You can somewhat indirectly opt-in to the optimizations by having your custom collection type implement `IList<T>`, but implement it explicitly and/or only ever expose your collection publicly as an `IEnumerable<T>`.  It's not ideal, but basically these are the optimization 'hooks'.  If you wanted to, you could provide a custom interface for each custom extension method that allows a class writer to override the extension method behavior, though this might get a bit cluttered.  Something like `WidgetExtensions.ToggleWidget(this Widget widget)` and `WidgetExtensions.IToggleWidget`.

Answer (score 12):

Calling `ElementAt` on an `IEnumerable<T>` will loop through the items until it reaches the desired index.  (An O(n) operation)

Calling `ElementAt` on an `IList<T>` (such as an array) will use the `IList<T>`'s indexer to immediately get the desired index.  (An O(1) operation)

Comment: Arh, so you are telling me that ElementAt is overloaded for Arrays, Lists, Whatnot..??

Comment: It's not overloaded.  It uses a type-cast.