# ElementAt(index) on ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, indexer

As a heads up, I'm learning C# at the moment and going through a textbook when I ran into this obstacle.

How do you call `ElementAt` from an `IEnumerable<T>`?
The second comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180091/understanding-the-extention-elementatindex?answertab=active#tab-top)
 SO question mentions it, but I just get an error.

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/elementat) they mention doing it as well, but they don't tell you **how**!

In case I'm missing something basic, here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Card {}

class Deck
{
    public ICollection<Card> Cards { get; private set; }

    public Card this[int index]
    {
        get { return Cards.ElementAt(index); }
    }
}
```

I've resorted to this from the information I got on the [MSDN Library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class Deck
{
    public ICollection<Card> Cards { get; private set; }

    public Card this[int index]
    {
        get {
        return System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt<Card>(Cards, index); 
        }
    }
}
```

All this comes from the section on collections and how the second code implementation I showed makes it easier to grab a specific element from the list rather than having to iterate through the enumerator.

```
Deck deck = new Deck();
Card card = deck[0];
```

Instead of:

```
Deck deck = new Deck();
Card c1 = null;
foreach (Card card in deck.Cards){
    if (condition for the index)
         c1 = card;
}
```

Am I doing this right or am I missing something? Thanks for any input!

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: you can't, the internal mechanism always uses some `Enumerator` and you can't jump right to an element and fetch it. Of course when you call `ToList` or some similar method, you actually iterate it once

Comment: the error i'm getting is that it can't find the definition

Comment: @KingKing Of course if `Cards` is actually an `IList`, `ElementAt` will use it's indexer anyway.

Comment: @p.s.w.g looks like the OP's cards is icollection, if it also implements IList, it's OK.

Comment: you guys are both right, but I was looking at how to call the indexer from ICollection for learning purposes. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use Linq [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), make sure you include the `System.Linq` namespace at the top of your file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; // This line is required to use Linq extension methods

class Card {}

class Deck
{
    public ICollection<Card> Cards { get; private set; }

    public Card this[int index]
    {
        get { return Cards.ElementAt(index); }
    }
}
```

Of course, extension methods are just regular old methods with a little bit of syntactic sugar. You could also call them this way:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Card {}

class Deck
{
    public ICollection<Card> Cards { get; private set; }

    public Card this[int index]
    {
        get { return System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt(Cards, index); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called an extension method.

Ensure you have `System.Linq` referenced.

Then just do `Cards.ElementAt(index)`

Perhaps you would like to use a `IList<T>` which has an indexer.

Comment: thanks, I thought I knew how extension methods work, but I guess I have to look into it in more detail

Answer (score 0):

The "simple" answer is that you should declare "Deck" as: IList (or Array ... basically the same for this discussion.)

The "Longer" answer lies in the confusion of "What is ICollection" ... ICollection is either 
(1) an IEnumerable with a known Count but NO known (or guaranteed) order.
(Imagine a data-store that knows the count but doesn't fix the order until you read the data.)
-or-
(2) an abstraction where you KNOW the count and have a known or dependable order, but do NOT naturally have random-access ... eg: a stack or a queue.

The *minor* difference is using IndexAt(int n) for #2 is O(1) (very fast), but O(n) (slower) NOT O(1) for #1 .

So, my conclusion is if you want random access, then pick data structure that you KNOW supports is (IList or Array, but not ICollection).